# Is there a reason to use *& or &* in C code?

Tags: c, dereference, unary-operator, addressof

I've come across some C code that make use of the reference/dereference (or whatever you choose to call them) operators, `*` and `&`, at the same time, like `&*foo` and `*&bar`. I'm puzzled by it. Is there any reason to do this?

Comment: Can you show us an example case (_not example code_)?

Comment: It's being used in simple variable assignments.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, they can be used meaningfully: a valid use case is in macro definitions to check that the macro argument matches the requirements.

`&*foo` verifies that `foo` is a pointer type (possibly after an implicit conversion from an array or function type).

`*&foo` verifies that `foo` is an lvalue expression.

For example, admittedly an example so simple that it might be a bit of macro abuse:

```
void f(int *);
#define F(x) (f(&*(x)))

void g(int *);
#if A
#define G(x) (g(x), (x)=0)
#elif B
#define G(x) (g(*&(x)))
#endif

void h(int *p, int i) {
  f(p); // okay
  F(p); // still okay, does the same thing as f(p)
  f(i); // typically just a compiler warning
  F(i); // pretty much always a compiler error

  g(p); // okay
  G(p); // okay
  g(p+0); // okay
  G(p+0); // error if A because of the modification
          // should be an error if B even without modification
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more concrete examples? Will help to understand your answer better. Thanks.

Comment: @StanislavPankevich Something like this? :)

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Could you also add an example for `*&foo verifies that foo is an lvalue expression.`?

Comment: @StanislavPankevich I can create an example where it's technically valid, but I don't have one readily available where it has any benefit. I'll try to add one later.

Comment: Would be great to have one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only meaningful reason to do so is to stop treating the expression as an *lvalue*.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.2

> The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type *‘‘type’’*,
>   the result has type *‘‘pointer to type’’*. If the operand is the result of a unary `*` operator,
>   neither that operator nor the `&` operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were
>   omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply **and the result is not an lvalue.**

Comment: When would you want to do that? I've never said to myself, "I sure wish this wasn't an lvalue."

Comment: @yellowantphil That's dependent, but in case of equality checks, it can help detecting `=` vs `==` issues.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I haven't ever seen people write `&*p1 == &*p2` to catch that. Have you?

Comment: @hvd no, I did not, but that's still possible. And echoing your question, I asked for the example to OP, in the first place. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. `&*ptr` contains a hint for the compiler that `ptr != NULL` (since otherwise `*ptr` would mean undefined behavior).
2. `*&` may be simply a result of a maintenance change where an auxiliary pointer variable was eliminated:

   ```
   struct {
       int i;
       double
   } x;

   void foo() {
       int* ip = &x.i;
       ...
       *ip = 1;
       ...
   }
   ```

   Straightforwardly replacing in the above code `ip` with `&x.i` results in code that can give birth to such a question on StackOverflow:

   ```
   struct {
       int i;
       double
   } x;

   void foo() {
       ...
       *&x.i = 1;  // <---
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Similarly `&*` may be introduced by a refactoring change that replaced lvalue with a pointer.

   Before refactoring:

   ```
   int main() {
       struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

       ...
       bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
       ...
   }
   ```

   After extracting the server setup code into a function of its own:

   ```
   void setup_server(struct sockaddr_in* serv_addr) {
       ...
       bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &*serv_addr, sizeof(*serv_addr));
       ...
   }

   int main() {
       struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

       ...
       setup_server(&serv_addr);
       ...
   }
   ```